# How does wordpress multisite manage subdomains?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, subdomain

I have a Wordpress multisite installed, and would like to understand how the subdomains actually are managed, ie how does my wordpress multisite knows where to find the files/data when a browser request URL `user1.domain.com` ?

I checked the DNS A record and see only the wild card.

I checked the .htaccess, and it looks as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Protect the htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>

# Protect wpconfig.php
<Files wp-config.php>
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>

# Disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

so I think the .htaccess does not manage the subdomain, or does it?

so then, how does my wordpress multisite knows where to find the files/data when a browser request URL  user1.domain.com ?

Comment: Might be able to get a better response here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I got an answer here:

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58285/how-does-wordpress-multisite-manage-subdomains